# What's the difference between "noun + pp" and "noun + that is pp"?

Tags: difference

Is this sentence correct in grammar?

> 'charcoal' is a black material ***used*** as fuel for fire.

If then, what's the difference with the below?

> 'charcoal' is a black material ***that is used*** as fuel for fire.

Comment: There is no difference in meaning between your two sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference in meaning and both sentences are grammatically fine. There's a difference in syntax.

> 'charcoal' is a black material [used as fuel for fire].

The bracketed expression is a past-participle functioning as a modifier of the noun "material".

> 'charcoal' is a black material [that ___ is used as fuel for fire]

The bracketed expression is a relative clause with a gap in the subject position, whose relativized element is "material" too.

Comment: Yes, I would just add that the past participial clause is a bare passive, as evident by the admissibility of a _by_ phrase.